# How do i modify this string with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, string

i have this string:

```
str = "<table><tr><td>!img! images/image1.jpeg !*img!</td><td> 12:34</td></tr><tr><td>!img! images/image2.jpeg !*img!</td><td>12:35</td><tr></table>;
```

I need to replace each occurrence of `!img! text.... !*img!` with `<img src="text...." />`

I'm not very good with RegExp, i tried so many things but none worked, the best i was able to come up with was:

```
str.replace(/(!img!)(.+)(!\*img!)/g,  '<img src="$2" />');
```

the problem however with the above code is that it selects the first `!img!` occurrence and the last `!*img!` occurrence ignoring everything between them!

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is by default greedy, and the `.+` will match as much text as possible. Try adding a ? after it so that your regex is `/(!img!)(.+?)(!\*img!)/`.

The question mark will give the plus sign "lazy" behavior, so it will instead try to match as little text as possible.

Comment: i didn't imaging that it has such an easy fix! but it worked :) thanks